# Redirecting from ane action to another controller action in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my code where I want to post some data(date of calendar here) to "index" action of "home" controller and want to save this data in the database and at the same time I want to redirect to another action of another controller i.e "Index" action of "Home" controller

here is my jquery code below,

```
  function getDate() {

            $('.cal_daybox').on('click', function () {

           var timestamp = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

                var day = new Date(timestamp);

                alert("You clicked " + day.toDateString());

                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")';
                var date = day.toDateString();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: { date: day.toDateString() },
                    dataType:"json"
                });                  
             return false;
            });
```

EventsController.cs

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Events.ToList());
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime date)
    {

            Date dt = new Date();
            dt.StartDate = date;
            db.Dates.Add(dt);   
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Events", new { id = dt.DateID });
    }
```

Comment: index action of events:: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Events.ToList());
        }

Comment: the issue is I am not able to post data and redirect to another page at the same time,Because in debugger it is showing me redirection but in actual  it is not getting redirected.

Comment: Ther is a lot missing here .you should not be posting a DateTime firstoff.it has to be some viewmodel.is your view strongly typed to a ViewModel class

Comment: I have tried by taking dateId as int but still it is not working.

Comment: is your post happening atleast?

Comment: yes.I am able to save dt.StartDate into database but only problem that it is not redirecting to the index action of Events controller

Comment: can u check my edited answer i have modified the param now for index

Comment: I had also tried it.but I think it is not redirecting because of the ajax post method that I used in the Index view of Home controller(You can check it in the first code block) to post the date.am I write?

Comment: I had also tried it.but I think it is not redirecting because of the ajax post method that I used in the Index view of Home controller(You can check it in the first code block) to post the date.am I write?

Answer (score 0):

Your Index Action of Events Controller does not have a parameter to recieve the Dateid value.It is unable to Find a Action that could recieve a DateId val.

You need to either modify your existing Action or add an Action Overload like this

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime dateId)
{
    //Do something with the val
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Events.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you are calling controller action using ajax so in this case you have to change you action method and jquery call like this:




         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Index(DateTime date)
         {

            Date dt = new Date();
            dt.StartDate = date;
            db.Dates.Add(dt);   
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(dt.DateID,JsonAllowBehaviour.AllowGet);
          // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Events", new { id = dt.DateID });
         }
    function getDate() {

            $('.cal_daybox').on('click', function () {

           var timestamp = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

                var day = new Date(timestamp);

                alert("You clicked " + day.toDateString());

                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")';
                var date = day.toDateString();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: { date: day.toDateString() },
                    dataType:"json",
                    onsuccess:function(id)
                                 {
window.location='/Events/Index?Id='+id;
                                  }
                });                  
             return false;
            });  


And also please change your index action of Events Controller like below:
public ActionResult Index(int Id=0)
{
    return View(db.Events.ToList());
}
```